# Multi-stage dividend discount model using financial calculator

Tags: equities, pricing, dividends

Instead of the wrote formula approach, [this analyst](https://www.analystforum.com/t/multi-period-ddm-with-financial-calculator/110158) shows that such problems can be decomposed into their cash flows at different points in time, which enables us to use `NPV` and `IRR` methods on a financial calculator to find the valuation as predicted by multi-stage DDM.

Although his answer was correct, I found it more intuitive to solve this way:

```
CF5 = 1
CF6 = 1.25
CF7 = 1.25^2 = 1.5625
CF8 = (1.25^3) + ((1.25^3 x 1.05)/0.103-0.05) = 40.64712
```

With those cashflows and `IRR` of 10.3% we still get the right answer of $20.65 after hitting the calculator's `CPT` button to find `NPV`.

So I thought, voila, this is awesome. But I encountered a different problem where I appear to be way off the mark using this approach.

> An analyst feels that Brown Company’s earnings and dividends will grow
> at 25% for two years, after which growth fill fall to a constant rate
> of 6%. If the projected discount rate is 10% and Browns most recently
> paid dividend was $1 the value of Brown’s stock using the multistage
> dividend discount model would be:
>
> A) 31.25
> B) 33.54
> C) 36.65

I interpreted this situation as follows:

```
CF0 = 1
CF1 = 1.25
CF2 = 1.25^2 = 1.5625
CF3 = 1.5625*1.06 + (1.5625*1.06)/(.1-.06) = 42.9688
```

With `IRR` at 10, the calculator gave me an `NPV` of 35.71. This matches none of the available choices. I fear I have blundered something.

### Question

What should be the proper sequencing of cashflow inputs if to solve "Brown Company" multi-stage DDM valuation on a financial calculator?

Comment: Shouldn’t your base in the third equation be 1.5625?

Comment: @BobJansen Right, was a typo, good catch. My calculator inputs were 1.5625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight mistake in one of the calculations to your solution to the second question (outcome of CF3 should be 43.06) but that's not the reason you are not getting a correct result.

I reckon you are using your financial calculator alright but you are misinterpreting the timing and progress of Brown Company's cash flows a bit. The company's cash flows, as described in the question, should be

```
CF0 = 0
CF1 = 1.25
CF2 = 1.25^2 + (1.25^2*1.06) / (0.10-0.06) = 42.97
```

If one discounts these at 10% per annum, their total present value comes to 36.65 which is the answer C.